# how to call a function and use a global variable in that function

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

so my goal is to separate the following tail recursion function into two functions.

```
let fib (n:int) :int = 
    let rec loop (i:int) (a:int) (b:int) :int  =
        if i = n then a
        else loop (i+1) (b) (a+b) in 
    loop 0 0 1;;
```

Comment: Well don't declare it as `loop` when you want to name it `fib_aux`?

Comment: And yes, you can't use `n` in that function. You would need to add a fourth parameter, and pass that through all of your recursive calls unaltered. (Or, you change how the function works, and let `i` decrement from `n` to `0` not increment it).

Comment: Title makes no sense. `n` is not global. It is a closure variable.

Comment: @rosababy please [edit] the code to fix typos and other minor details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not sure how to use `n` in loop function.

You can't, that what makes nested function definitions so popular :-) You would need to add a fourth parameter, and pass that through all of your recursive calls unaltered:

```
let rec loop i n a b = 
  if i = n then a
  else loop (i+1) (n) (b) (a+b) 

let fib n = 
  loop 0 n 0 1
```

Alternatively, you change the looping structure so that it doesn't count `i` up from `0` to `n`, but rather have a variable (say `j`) count down from `n` so you only need to check when it reaches `0` in `loop`:

```
let rec loop j a b = 
  if j = 0 then a
  else loop (j-1) (b) (a+b) 

let fib n = 
  loop n 0 1
```

Comment: for the second alternative one, n is still unbound to the loop function though.

Comment: @rosababy Yes, but you don't need any `n` in there any more. (Although, naming the new variable `n` - instead of `j` - is rather common)

Comment: placing j last is also most common and then you can use `let rec loop a b = function 0 -> a | n -> loop b (a + b) (n - 1)`